# How can i specify bash function to scp -S as argument

Tags: bash, shell, scp

scp -S  is what the documentation says...if i create a perl/bash script with file name scon it works...however if i create a bash function say scon

```
function scon () {
...
...
}
```

and try to pass scon as argument to -S option i.e as follows

```
scp -S scon ...
```

it says scon: No such file or directory

Is there a way to tell scp to invoke this bash function as command instead of trying to run this as a script file.

Comment: I tried "eval scon" and even that did not seem to work.

Comment: No there is not. The program that scp -S expects must be a a file that can be executed, scp does not know how to run a perl or  bash function.

Comment: The closest i found so far is:   echo "scon \"\$@\"" > ~/scon
  echo -n "function " >> ~/scon
  declare -f scon >> ~/scon

Comment: You can also create a bash script and have scp execute that. Add the usual `#!/bin/sh` at the start of the file, place the content of your scon function in that file and make the file executable.